# opendaylight Openflow plugin create a flow table

Tags: openflow, opendaylight

I am porting an application from RYU to opendaylight. I am using the opendaylight openflow plugin and working with the Carbon distribution. I am writing an openflow Karaf application (bundle).  I need multiple flow tables in my application. I am looking for any guidance on how to create a flow table in the openflow plugin. Any pointers or code fragments to accomplish the above would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by looking at the code in the genius project for inspiration... checkout out e.g.  org.opendaylight.genius.mdsalutil.internal.MDSALManager - that's the utility using which the genius and netvirt ODL projects write flows.

You don't actually have to use that directly yourself (you could, but don't really have it, it's just a layer on top of openflowplugin), but poking around that code may help you with what you seem to want to learn about.

Comment: I see that Transactions / rollback etc are implemented there already. Perhaps I should start using the genius feature.